# Eclipse plugin for CSS intellisense

Tags: css, eclipse-plugin, aptana

in my Eclispe IDE i'd like to have intellisense for css in HTML, XHTML, JSF etc. files.
Is there a good lightweight plugin besides Aptana IDE?

THX

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any other solution for this, so I used Aptana Eclipse Plugin. After editing your projectsettings it work's perfect.

[Set projectstettings](http://www.fene-blog.de/en/webdesign/aptanastudio2/aptana-erkennt-bei-css-die-class-und-id-namen-nicht-mehr/)

So far ...